# Multiple while loops with printf in C

Tags: c

So I need to printf X 10 times in 5 rows, here is my code. I am not sure how to separate those X in rows, every time I use \n, \t or something similar it will make X go vertical, but i need it to be 10 X i one row and 10 X in another and so on. Also I can only use nested while loop nothing else. Some help? :D

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
int d = 0;
int e = 0;

while (a <= 9) {
    while (b <= 9) {
        while (c <= 9) {
            while (d <= 9) {
                while (e <= 9) {
                    printf("X");
                    e++;
                }
                printf("X");
                d++;
            }
            printf("X");
            c++;
        }
        printf("X");
        b++;
    }
    printf("X");
    a++;
}
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: **HINT :** For your problem you only need 2 loops..

Comment: Your should try to ask more general things. People in general don't care if you need 10x10 X to be printed, or 1x1, or 3x5. Your problem seems to be related to a more general thing like: How can I print some organize text in C? Also, you claim that '\t' doesn't work as it print your text vertically, just as if you were using '\n'. While I don't beleave in that statement, you should provide some example highlighting this behaviour.

Comment: Okay, I will try some things that Haris and Emandi suggested. I am new to all of this, and to this forum too so it's hard to shuffle thru finding answer here for me at least. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To printf X 10 times in 5 rows, draw a row of 10 'X's first, and then repeat this operation 5 times:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int rowCount = 0, columnCount = 0;
    while(rowCount < 5) // Five rows
    {
        columnCount = 0;
        while(columnCount < 10) // Ten columns
        {
            putchar('X');
            columnCount++;
        }
        putchar('\n'); // End of a row
        rowCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's okay but I can only use while loop, no for. And it seems that I can't make it work, I get eather vertical X or one row of X.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rowCount=5;
while(rowCount)
{
    var columnCount=10;
    while(columnCount)
    {
        putchar('X');
        columnCount--;
    }
    putchar('\n');
    rowCount--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int row=0, column=0;

    while (row<=4)
    {
        column=0;
        while (column<=9)
        {
            putchar('X');
            column++;
        }
        putchar('\n'); 
        row++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a description of what your code is doing to help the OP understand it better.